# Product prices including/excluding tax dependent customer session

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, tax, session

In Magento Backend Configuration Settings > Tax > Price Display settings 
"Display Product Prices In Catalog" is set to "Including and Excluding Tax".

In front-end , 
If customer is logged in and is assigned to 21% Tax Group, Products are shown as 
Excl. Tax: 4,12 USD
Incl. Tax: 4,99 USD

If a customer is logged in and is assigned to Zero Tax Group, Products are shown as 
Excl. Tax: 4,12 USD
Incl. Tax: 4,12 USD

I want to override the "Display Product Prices In Catalog" as

If a customer is logged in and has ZERO Tax% Group then

"Display Product Prices In Catalog" is set to "Excluding Tax". Means it will show one price on pages.

Else

"Display Product Prices In Catalog" is set to "Including and Excluding Tax". Which will display price like below:
Excl. Tax: 4,12 USD
Incl. Tax: 4,99 USD

I was planing to rewrite class where they are getting this config setting. But after searching on code I found that it has been used in so many place. I can achieve this by rewriting but is there any another approach that I can adopt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just check in `price.phtml` if the two prices are the same, if yes, show only one of them.